# Strange debugging behaviour using class library

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, class-library

I have a VB.NET class library, ConsoleControls, which has a few class objects designed to imitate Forms objects in Console mode. For example, there is a ProgressBar class which draws an ASCII progress bar set at a certain value. I've been using this library in my main project, TheGame.

The code is functional, but when I use the class objects and methods in my main project, I've been getting strange behaviour when debugging. For example, when I call the ProgressBar class's Draw method, the yellow arrow showing which line is about to be executed appears at the End Sub for that method. Then of all things it starts running through a completely different class, TextBox, which has nothing to do with ProgressBar. It repeats certain lines multiple times. It's as if the debugger is running a completely different portion of code to what it shows me it's running.

Here's the ProgressBar class:

```
Public Class ProgressBar
    Public InactiveColour As ConsoleColor
    Public ActiveColour As ConsoleColor
    Public Position As Point
    Public Length As Integer
    Public Value As Integer
    Public MaxValue As Integer
    Public Sub New(_Position As Point, _Length As Integer, _InactiveColour As ConsoleColor, _ActiveColour As ConsoleColor)
        Position = _Position
        Length = _Length
        InactiveColour = _InactiveColour
        ActiveColour = _ActiveColour
    End Sub
    Public Sub SetValue(_Value As Integer, _MaxValue As Integer)
        Value = _Value
        MaxValue = _MaxValue
    End Sub
    Public Sub IncrementValue()
        If Value + 1 <= MaxValue Then Value += 1
    End Sub
    Public Sub DecrementValue()
        If Value - 1 >= 0 Then Value -= 1
    End Sub
    Public Sub Draw()
        Dim ActiveBars, InactiveBars As Integer
        Dim Divisor As Double
        Divisor = MaxValue / Length
        ActiveBars = CInt(Value / Divisor)
        InactiveBars = Length - ActiveBars

        Console.SetCursorPosition(Position.X, Position.Y)
        Console.ForegroundColor = ActiveColour

        For i = 1 To ActiveBars
            Console.Write(Block)
        Next

        Console.ForegroundColor = InactiveColour
        For i = 1 To InactiveBars
            Console.Write(Block)
        Next

        Console.ResetColor()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here's the code that does weird things in my main project:

```
Dim PlayerHealthBar As ProgressBar
PlayerHealthBar = New ProgressBar(New Point(30, 4), 32, ConsoleColor.DarkGray, ConsoleColor.White)
PlayerHealthBar.SetValue(1, 10)
PlayerHealthBar.Draw()
```

Any suggestions as to what may be going on?

Comment: Try Project > Rebuild All Solution, and then debug again. Just in case...

Comment: In the class library or the main project?

Comment: Worked like a dream! If you could add that as an answer then I shall accept it :)